# Local Variable / Class variable increment

Tags: c++, printing, pass-by-value

So essentially what my program does is read in a data stream of words, and count the occurrence of each word, and the total number of unique words. It will will read them into a map. My program works perfectly except for one problem...when I call `p.print()`, the value for `total` is still at 0. There seems to be some problem where total is incremented in the for_each statement, but when I p.print, it acts as if was never incremented...My print function is defined as follows:

```
void print_words(const map<string,int> &aMap) {
    PRN p(aMap.size());
    for_each(aMap.begin(), aMap.end(), p);
    p.print();
}
```

I have a class that is in charge of processing each word, here is the definition:

```
//CLASS PRN FUNCTIONS
// constructor
PRN::PRN(const int& s, const int& c, const int& t) {
    sz=s;
    cnt=c;
    total=t;
}

// overloaded operator, where P is defined as
// typedef pair < string, int > P;
void PRN::operator()(const P& p) {
    if(cnt%NO_ITEMS == 0 && cnt != 0)
        cout << '\n';
    cout << setw(ITEM_W) << left << p.first << " : " << setw(NO_W) << left << p.second;
    total += p.second;
    cnt++;
}

// to printout final value of total                                                             
void PRN::print() const {
    cout << '\n' << '\n';
    cout << "no of words in input stream  : " << total << endl;
    cout << "no of words in output stream : " << sz << endl;
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured out your problem, but please name your variables, classes, functions and arguments better than that. Being descriptive helps everyone else who reads your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...I need to have

```
p = for_each(aMap.begin(), aMap.end(), p);
```

No better feeling then figuring out your own problem!